# No hex number 10 in python?

Tags: python, hex

I am wondering, why there is no b'\x0a' number in python. For example, if I execute

```
print(bytes([10]))
```

the result is

```
b'\n'
```

but I would expect

```
b'\x0a'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The bytes type is very 'helpful' and replaces some 'obscure' hex numbers (`b'\x0a'` in your example) with the more easily readable `b'\n'`.

Comment: `(b'\x0a' == b'\n') == True`

Answer (score 1):

Python 3 prints the ASCII representation of the provided bytes. 
In ASCII, 10 is equal to the newline character ("\n").

The following code fragment will print the hex representation:

```
print(bytes([10]).hex())
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try `hex` function

```
print(hex(10)) #=> 0xa
```